# can't get 'scope' value from core_config_data table

Tags: mysql, core, scope, core-config-data

I need to make an sql sentence where i retrieve records filtered by 'scope' value from core_config_data table. This is the script:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `core_config_data` WHERE  `scope` = $scope";
```

I get $scope with this line:

```
$scope = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config_data')->getScope();
```

But when i run this, i receive an error saying:

**An error occurred while saving this configuration: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'stores' in 'where clause'**

When i run the same sql sentence in phpmyadmin, it works fine and it retrieves the correct record, so i don't know what's wrong here.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you don't escap `$scope`, so mysql thinks that the value of `$scope` is a column instead of a string. add a few ` around it.

Comment: Thanks dude, in fact i had to add ' to the variable. Cheers.-